# clicar em um link e exibir em um textarea um codigo html

Tags: javascript

como eu faria pra quando eu clicar em um determinado link por exemplo `<a href='javascript:void(0)'>Capitulo</a>` exibisse em uma `textarea` as tags `<strong></strong>`, entre outros link's que eu vou ter para exibir tags diferentes

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var els = document.body.querySelectorAll("a[href*='java']");
  for (var x = 0; x < els.length; x++) {
    els[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var a_txt = this.textContent,
        inpt = document.body.querySelector("#versiculos");
      inpt.value += " " + a_txt;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Capitulo</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Versículo</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Destaque</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Link's</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Quebra de linhas</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: vais ter que dar mais contexto (html e explicação) para que se possa entender o que queres fazer

Comment: ao clicar em Capitulo, ele imprima em uma textarea as tags ´<strong></strong>´, e assim para cada link, cada link corresponde a uma tag diferente